# POE-Component-IRC crashes under Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: perl, components, irc, poe

I'm trying to run the Perl module POE-Component-IRC using Perl v5.12.13 with ActiveState under Windows 7 64-bit and each time it is run it crashes Windows. I'm pretty sure it's something to do with this module since the only lines I have in the script is shown below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use POE qw(Component::IRC);
```

When I run this file Windows gets the gets the generic "This program has stopped responding" error message.

According to http://code.activestate.com/ppm/POE-Component-IRC/ it appears that it is compatible with my Perl version and version of Windows.

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated. I'd contact the developer on SourceForge but every time I report a but I get an error.

Comment: Don't report bugs on SourceForge, report bugs in the place that the distribution metadata says bugs are *supposed* to go to — in this case, https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=POE-Component-IRC or bug-POE-Component-IRC@rt.cpan.org

Comment: In addition to hobbs' comment, you should always check search.cpan.org and/or metacpan.org for the proper place to report bugs.  While there may be a bug tracker at SourceForge, it's not necessarily canonical.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have latest version - 6.78.

Did you install it with ppm? In that case you should test it - run `cpan -t POE::Component::IRC`.

Correct place for reporting bugs is [bug tracker](https://rt.cpan.org/Dist/Display.html?Name=POE-Component-IRC)